# npm config set command not working properly

Tags: npm, npm-config

i set the default config for the package.json file using the command,

```
npm config set init-main "script.js"
```

after this i initialized a folder using

```
npm init --yes
```

but the main is still "index.js". But, if i write

```
npm config get init-main
```

it returns "script.js". I could not find anything related in the documentation. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `npm config set` allows you to set **anything**, eg. you can do something like:

```
npm config set foo "bar"
npm config get foo  # outputs: bar
```

**You probably just want to edit in `package.json` the field `main` to `"index.js"`,** there does not appear to exist any such config for npm (no `init-main` described https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config). Maybe an older/unstable verion had it?

(npm config should probably show a warning or somerhing in this case, like "warning, unrecognized config 'init-main'", but it doesn't...)

Answer (score 0):

The following command.
npm pkg set main=script.js